# Can't center my image in css and can't remove horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center .front on the page but can't seem to do so. Also there is a horizontal scrollbar and I don't know why or how to get rid of it. When I try overflow-x:hidden; .front gets cut off and vertical scroll get shortened.

Here's the css

```
body{
font-family: 'Proza Libre', sans-serif;
background-color:#f7f3de;
}
.para{
text-align:left;
position:relative;
display:inline;
right:-100px;
}
.links{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
font-size:20px;
top:-50px;
word-spacing:30px;
}
.logo{
position:relative;
display:box;
float:right;
width:16%;
top:-100px;
right:100px;

}
.front{
position:relative;
top:100px;
display:box;
float:center;   
}
```

This is the html

```
    <div class="para">
    <h1>Beach Corp Inc.</h1>
    </div>
        <div class="links">
        <a href="asdasd.com">FAQ</a>
        <a href="asdasd.com">About</a>
        <a href="asdasd.com">Social</a>
       <a href="asdasd.com">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="http://samuibeautifulbeachvillas.com/assets/samui-beautiful-
beach-villas.png" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="http://www.beaches.com/assets/img/home/rst-btc.jpg" class="front">
    </div>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Proza Libre', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f7f3de;
}

.para {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  right: -100px;
}

.links {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: -50px;
  word-spacing: 30px;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: box;
  float: right;
  width: 16%;
  top: -100px;
  right: 100px;
}

.front {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  display: box;
  float: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="para">
  <h1>Beach Corp Inc.</h1>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a href="asdasd.com">FAQ</a>
  <a href="asdasd.com">About</a>
  <a href="asdasd.com">Social</a>
  <a href="asdasd.com">Contact</a>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://samuibeautifulbeachvillas.com/assets/samui-beautiful-
beach-villas.png" class="logo">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.beaches.com/assets/img/home/rst-btc.jpg" class="front">
</div>
```

Comment: I've copied this into JSFiddle but because we don't know that realbeach.png is I'm not sure what issue you're talking about, can you try to get the issue replicated on JS fiddle so we can help  https://jsfiddle.net/g41z4wup/

Comment: I added an image you can use

Comment: `display:box` means nothing, for starters

Comment: The `display: box;` and `float: center;` rules are invalid. Try `display: block;` and `margin: auto;` instead to center `.font`

Answer (score 2):

This will center your div `front`.

```
.front{
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;  
}
```

For your scrollbar, it's hard without seeing the code but if you add an `overflow:hidden` to your wrapper element it should solve the problem

Comment: I did that, it moved but its still not perfectly centered and the scrollbar is still there.

Comment: @Lucas can you show us what it looks like at your side.

Comment: @Lucas If it isn't centered then there is something else blocking it, you should post your code

Answer (score 1):

Use this to hide horizontal scrollbar:

```
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

And this to center image:

```
   img{
     display:block;
     margin: auto;  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow-x: hidden;` to hide your horizontal scrollbar and for centering just set `margin:auto;`